# Asynchronously uploading user sign up information while performing a segue method

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am building a social app so I need to sign up users. These users will have their own profiles will bio's, pictures, etc. So after the users sign up I want to direct them straight to a view controller that will allow them to input the information that will go onto their profile. I have created a segue that goes directly to this page and is activated when the user presses the sign up button. However, because I need to upload the user information asynchronously, there is an error that says "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid class name. Class names cannot start with an underscore."

Here is the segue method please let me know if their is anything I can do differently:

```
- (BOOL) shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)showBuildProfile sender:(id)sender {

        NSString *firstname = [self.firstNameField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        NSString *lastname = [self.lastNameField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        NSString *username = [self.userField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        NSString *password = [self.passwordField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        NSString *email = [self.emailField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

        if ([firstname length] == 0 || [lastname length] == 0 || [username length] == 0 || [password length] == 0 || [email length] == 0) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops" message:@"Make sure you fill in all of the information." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
            return NO;
        } else {
            PFUser *newUser = [PFUser user];
            newUser.username = username;
            newUser.password = password;
            newUser.email = email;

            newUser[@"first name"] = self.firstNameField;
            newUser[@"last name"] = self.lastNameField;


            [newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){
                if (error) {
                    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry!" message:[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"error"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alertView show];
                } else {
                    //Sign up the user.
                }
            }];
            return YES; }
}
```

Also, the program runs completely fine until I input information into the textfields and press the sign up button.

Comment: Shouldn't the "Sign up" button sign up the user, instead opening the "Profile" page? IMO, the sign_up task should be asynchronous and the completion handler should open the profile page.

Comment: I want the sign up button to sign up the user. But I also want it to open a "build profile" page where the user can input the information that will go onto their profile. I'm not sure what other method I could use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending the user to a new View via segue right away, I would suggest that you put up a 'loading view' while you asynchronously upload their data. Then when you receive your response from the server that it's all good, close the loading view and segue over to their profile view.

[image: Example from my own app]

Comment: Thank you, it seems like a feasible method, but how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Essentially, when the user hits signup, you either addSubview of your special loading view so it's in front or simply bring it to the front (if its hidden behind the current view). Then you execute your asynchronous method(s) and when they finish, they will move the loading view back to the back (or remove from superview) and segue the user to the next page with the updated data.